# Using Windows Authentication in Blazor WebAssembly with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've been researching and testing out something that seems so simple, and yet just will not work for me.

I just want to get the current User Principal with Windows Authentication, but it seems that the Authentication Scheme is not hooked up properly?

[image]

This is when I add the Authorize attribute to the controller that just gets the User.Identity.Name value:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("getUser")]
public string? GetUser()
{
    return User?.Identity?.Name;
}
```

This is just the blazor wasm template sample in VS 2022, so in Program:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.Negotiate);
```

When I remove the Authorize, and inspect the User Principal, it has a single Claim that is empty.

Have Windows Auth on in launch settings:

```
"iisSettings": {
      "windowsAuthentication": true,
      "anonymousAuthentication": true,
      "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:31120",
        "sslPort": 44346
      }
    },
    "profiles": {
      "BlazorApp2.Server": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "windowsAuthentication": true,
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7139;http://localhost:5139",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      },
```

Obviously, I'm doing something really silly, but can someone please enlighten me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems that I got it working by pulling in the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate** package.

And switching to the *Negotiate* AutheniticationScheme. I thought I'd tried this, but must have had something not quite right:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
```

I also noticed that the **Authorize** attribute is required on the controller action otherwise the User Principle is still empty?